# Is there a @HMTL.ACtionLink or some method that is similar to create a link to outside web pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a link say to www.google.com. Is there an extension method similar to @HTML.ACtionLink that will allow me to do this?

Or should i use the  tag in html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionLink` helpers are useful for routing to different parts of your application. This does not apply to external links since there are no action methods nor route links associated with it. Add an anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://wwww.google.com">Clicky!</a>
```